# geolocation: finding addresses of people on a street

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I've looked at several of the geolocation providers (google, yahoo, etc.) and have been unable to find data that I expected to be readily available: all residential addresses along a given street.

An example query would be:

```
"return a list of the residential addresses on 'mystreet, mycity, mystate' within a 1000 meter radius"
```

Did I miss something obvious or are the providers who *can* do this (e.g. spokeo.com) using their own data?

TIA

Comment: As this information is not readily available you will need to pay for this.

Comment: Thank you @davidstrachan. Do you have any suggestions as to which provider I might contact?

Comment: IN the UK the Royal Mail provide such information. Other countries may or not have such services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) for your task. For example [this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/11b) returns all addresses belonging to the street *Prager Straße* in the city *Dresden*. It uses [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) to visualize the data and the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) in the background for running the actual query. Of course you can also run the query directly for returning [raw data](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%20%3Cosm-script%20output%3D%22json%22%3E%20%3Cunion%3E%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22node%22%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Astreet%22%20v%3D%22Prager%20Stra%C3%9Fe%22%2F%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Acity%22%20v%3D%22Dresden%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22way%22%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Astreet%22%20v%3D%22Prager%20Stra%C3%9Fe%22%2F%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Acity%22%20v%3D%22Dresden%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22relation%22%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Astreet%22%20v%3D%22Prager%20Stra%C3%9Fe%22%2F%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22addr%3Acity%22%20v%3D%22Dresden%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%20%3C%2Funion%3E%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22body%22%2F%3E%20%3Crecurse%20type%3D%22down%22%2F%3E%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22skeleton%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fosm-script%3E). If you want to modify the query conditions take a look at all commonly used [address tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aaddr). To modify the query take a look at the [Overpass API language guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide).